# How to insert a GIS online service in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I want to download or digitize some data from an online GIS server(http://gis.chania.gr/).

Is there any way to insert that site or download data from it?

Comment: You probably should ask the website owner. Its using ArcGIS online / JS API, so using the account without permission isn't a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to GIS stackexchange.  You won't get downvoted if you do some more research before asking questions.  Also try to be very detailed and specific with your questions.  List things you have tried and what has not worked.  Thanks!

Comment: We have already ask them. They are in hollidays and the don't respond 20days know. That's why I asked here. :/

Answer (score 1):

You can use their WMS, which was listed on their site:

http://gis.ktimanet.gr/wms/wmsopen/wmsserver.aspx

Details about the data and access constraints are listed here:

http://www.ktimatologio.gr/sites/en/Pages/News.aspx?tid=21

In QGIS, add WMS and enter the address.

Comment: I know how to enter Ktimanet from Greece in QGIS. The point was to insert the layers from http://gis.chania.gr/.

Comment: You may be able to get some information out of the service provider.  Here's the website:  http://www.elpho.gr/